# fetch y axios , incluso async me devuelven promise pending y el valor dentro en fullfield

Tags: javascript, fetch, axios, promesas, async-await

He hecho anteriormente mas funciones async y todas me devuelven bien los datos, pero no entiendo que pasa ahora que no es asi.
Probe con el ejemplo mas sencillo de jsonplaceholder que en su web si le das te devuelve el objeto pero si lo hago yo, me devuelve promise pending, y dentro de esa promise si la abro en la consola aparece en promiseResult el array pero claro, asi si lo meto a una variable y quiero hacerle map no me deja porque detecta que es objeto por la promesa.

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Este codigo si lo ejectuo ahora en stackoverflow me saca solo el objeto, pero si lo ejecuto en mi runjs, o en mi navegador, en mi projecto react, me saca siempre
promise pending
y si la abres esta el promiseResult que contiene el objeto

Añado codigo en react, de mi componente prueba api

```
    const getDatos = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  };

let datos = getDatos()
console.log(getDatos())

return(
  {data.map(item => console.log(item))}
)
```

queria sacarlo por consola para posteriormente meterlo en divs pero me al devolverme una promesa pendiente que dentro de ella tiene el promiseResult con los datos no me carga
ya que lo que pilla la variable es el objeto promesa

Comment: Si haces `const a = fetch(...); console.log(a)`, pues claro que te va a devolver promise pending... pero si solo haces `fetch(...)..then(json => console.log(json))` el console,log si debería traer los datos, como en el ejemplo que pusiste aqui en stackOverflow

Comment: pero necesito guardar los datos en una variable para mapearlo

Comment: entonces usa `const a = await fecth(...)`, así esperas que la promesa se resuelva y `a` contendrá el valor del objeto. Si quieres comparte el código que realmente estás usando para ayudarte.

Comment: me dice que solo es valido in funciones asyncronas

Comment: Yo he hecho eso mil veces en react, comparte tu código real para poder seguir ayudandote. Ya que editaste tu comentario anterior... si, tiene que ser llamado desde una funcion asincrona... pero insisto, comparte tu código y te ayudo a solucionarlo

Comment: Pero en que parte del código de react estás haciendo ese llamado?

Comment: es que lo he probado en runjs y otros sitios y ni en vanilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes hacer como te expliqué:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [datos, setDatos] = useState(null);
  
  const getDatos = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setDatos(data);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getDatos()
  }, []);
  
  return <div>{!datos ? "Cargando..." : datos.map(dato => <div>{dato.title}</div>)}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Aqui lo puedes ver en vivo:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-playground-forked-3lhvw7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

En vanilla javascript sería similar:

```js
 const getDatos = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
};
  
const cargarYmostrarDatos = async () => {
  const data = await getDatos();
  console.log(data);
}

cargarYmostrarDatos()
```

Comment: Genial, en react funciona demaravilla, si esto quisiera hacerlo en javascript vanilla, como lo haria para que no me devuelva pending?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta

Comment: Vaaale era eso justo lo que me faltaba saber, hay que usar otra funcion, de verdad muchisimas gracias ahora entiendo mejor todo

Comment: Si, `await` no se puede usar en el bloque principal de código, debes crear una función `async` y usarlo allá (pero esto probablemente cambie en el futuro en las próximas versiones de javascript). Saludos